# MS SQL аудирование

Tags: sql-server

Что произойдёт если выделенное место под файл для записи аудита закончится, при том, что автоматически выделение памяти под аудит выключен?
Так же вопрос, что произойдёт если во время аудита удалить файл для записи аудита? Ms sql создаст новый файл?

Comment: в случае сбоя инициации аудита запуск экземпляра сервера завершится неудачей, хотя запустить его можно принудительно с помощью параметра -f в командной строке

Comment: в SQL Server 2012 предусмотрен другой вариант: ограничение файлов без переключения. Таким образом можно управлять количеством информации, сохраняемой без потери записей аудита.

Чтобы ограничить число файлов без переключения, используйте параметр MAX_FILES в инструкции CREATE SERVER AUDIT. При наличии этого параметра SQL Server блокирует и откатывает любые операции после того, как достигнут предел, пока администратор не очистит файлы.

Comment: MySql и Sql Server - это две **разные** СУБД. Какую именно вы используете? | Примечание: нет такой СУБД - MS Sql.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , я думаю всем и так понятно о чем речь

Comment: Тогда удалите лишнюю метку. / И я ещё раз повторяю: нет такой СУБД - MS Sql. СУБД от Microsoft называется Sql Server.